# How do I add the 'Add To Favourites' Feature into a Tab Bar App?

Tags: iphone

I'm just wondering what code I would use to add a 'Add To Favourites' feature into my app?

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: You question is quite broad, could you address what specifically you are trying to add as a favorite? Music, Contacts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need some type of persistent storage. Depending on what you're adding, you may be able to use NSUserDefaults, or you might need a .plist or you might need something more robust like Core Data. Really hard to say without knowing your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Already i did a add to favourites concept.First you create  a table(id,fieldname1,fieldname2,status) in sqlite.Then insert your data into a corresponding fields. this is my code.i have just pass the id and update the staus

-(void)updatedata {

```
NSString * dt=show.id;

const char *sql = "update quotesdet set status = ? where id = ?;";


    if ((sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &updateStmt, NULL))!=SQLITE_OK)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"DatabaseNotAvailable", @"") message:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:sqlite3_errmsg(database)]
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];   
        [alert release];

    }

NSString *s = @"true";

sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 1, [s UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
NSInteger n = [dt intValue];
sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 2, n);
int success = sqlite3_step(updateStmt);
if (success == SQLITE_ERROR) {
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to insert into the database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    //return NO;
}
else {

    sqlite3_finalize(updateStmt);

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Added Successfully"
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];   
    [alert release];

}
```

}